# How to concat two strings in setText() in Android

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to do something like this:

```
mMovieName.setText(R.string.name + movieDetailsResponse.getTitle());
```

Expected Display : **Name: Titanic**

Actual Display : **2131165233Titanic**

Can someone tell me how can I achieve expected display. I dont want to hardcode the string in TextView like this :

```
mMovieName.setText("Name: " + movieDetailsResponse.getTitle());
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Formatting strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling).

Your `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="name">Name: %1$s</string>
```

Your Java code:

```
mMovieName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.name,  movieDetailsResponse.getTitle()));
```

Output:

> Name: Titanic

Answer (score 1):

Hello use below code,

```
mMovieName.setText(getString(R.string.name) + movieDetailsResponse.getTitle());
```

Comment: Thanks .. this worked.. I will accept the answer in 10 minutes as the system wont allow me to it before that

Comment: @Sushil maybe it worked but this is not a good solution, see Niranj Patel answer instead (using `Resources#getString(int id, Object... formatArgs)`)

Comment: @pskink .. both are same solution. As I was using the function in fragment, I didnt need to explicitly call getResources

Comment: @Sushil no they are not, if you need a fragment then simply use `Fragment#getString(int resId, Object... formatArgs)`

Comment: @Sushil It's not the same. One uses formatting strings (good), one uses concatenation, which is no better than hardcoding (bad).

Comment: @pskink .. indeed i realized that and so have marked other answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `R.string.name` with `getResources().getString(R.string.name)`
because `R.string.name` is not a string but an Id of this string.

```
mMovieName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.name) + movieDetailsResponse.getTitle());
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do

```
mMovieName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.name) + movieDetailsResponse.getTitle());
```

Comment: You should not. What if in another language the movie title goes first?

Comment: @EugenPechanec he asked why the string was being returned as an int and I answered his question. Also he never asked or said that he might want to use another language. And finally, that is not relevant since in the example that I said `Name:` will always appear first.

Comment: `he asked [...] and I answered his question.` I must disagree, you posted some code without an explanation. You also ignored the second part of the question `I dont want to hardcode the string`. Concatenating two strings in Java is still a form of hardcoding (the order of strings is defined at use site). Formatting strings (the accepted answer) is better option. /// I like to think the community is here to help askers grow, in this case help OP become better Android developer by learning best practices.

Comment: Your answer is also redundant as two other people came up with the exact same thing. Always provide extra value.

Comment: `Your answer is also redundant as two other people came up with the exact same thing.` When I answered the question, there was no other answer at that time. I agree that the answered selected is better but I don't agree that concatenating two strings is a form of hardcoding. For me that is a little farfetched.